# Question Appropriate

Tags: discussion

Dear Sound Design Community,

Please let me know if this question is appropriate for this community.

### **Recommendation for Connecting Multiple Wireless Headphones to a Television to Play Audio through the Television and Headphones Simultaneously**

### Background

My grandparents are practically deaf. In order for them to "hear" sound, the television has to be close to max volume.

I understand the solution is to have them wear hearing aids. Unfortunately, they refuse.

**Is it possible to have both the audio play from the television and to wireless headphones as well?**

### Current Setup

The TV Is connected to their cable box via HDMI where the TV outputs sound.

This is the back of their cable box
[image: Back of Optimum Online Cable Box- Samsung]

---

I have researched a fair amount into this and am no expert.

To the best of my knowledge, it is possible to do this from a **computer**, but I am not sure for a **television**.

The solutions involve playing audio through HDMI through the TV as well as the audio jack of the TV.

-->"http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/is-it-possible-to-have-speakers-and-hdmi-play-at/4563a5f8-4be4-4463-b312-eff594a9ae49"

My proposed solution was to get try and mimic the computer solution by using something like this [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BIQER0E](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BIQER0E)

J-Tech Digital ® Premium Quality 1080P HDMI To HDMI + Audio (SPDIF + RCA Stereo) Audio Extractor Converter

- Extract the digital HDMI audio signal from the HDMI input and convert it to 2 channel analog stereo output or 5.1 channel Audio output

  ---

My only issue with this solution, is the ability to use more than two wireless headphones at the same time. I would need to connect about 6 wireless headphones. I was going to use these Power Acoustik Farenheit HP-902 RFT headphones.

**Is there a splitter or switch for the red and white audio output that would allow this?** I have seen splitters and switches that allow you to switch to different inputs, but not all at the same time.

I really appreciate any type of input, please correct me if said something incorrect or silly.

~TT

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, Home Audio/Audiophile questions are specifically off-topic.  There is a related category of professional questions dealing with Distribution Amplifiers that would be on topic, but you should generalize the problem before posting it to be specific to trying to replicate an audio signal for multiple listeners or for wireless distribution.

It gets tricky when specifically a home audio concern because there are consumer products that may do it that would be off topic, but there are also professional audio ways to handle the general problem.

Details specific to the wireup of the home theater system are still going to be explicitly off topic though.  We just might be able to help some with the general signal duplication aspect.

You may also be able to find what you need from things like 
[How to build a 3.5mm jack distributor](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/30012/how-to-build-a-3-5mm-jack-distributor/) or looking for more questions related to Distribution Amplifiers.

Comment: I appreciate the response. There is a reason why I posted it in Meta.  I will think about your suggestion and try and rephrase it to be more general.